# How to trigger the Junit/Testng tests to run by clicking from a web interface

Tags: maven, testing, selenium, automation, testng

This is a JAVA Testing webapp Project (Using maven, TESTNG, SELENIUM, JAVA 1.7)

I used the TestNG framwork to develop my selenium tests. 
Currently, I can do "mvn test"  and browsers will pops up and my selenium tests will run.

In order to run these tests on different instances,
I can change parameter "test_website="http://www.google_instance1.com" to "test_website="http://www.google_instance2.com" in the config testng.xml

My goal:
I want to design a web interface, which have a textbox[for entering the webapp's ip or hostname] and a submit button [which trigger all the selenium tests to start].

Feature:
User can put the webapp's ip or hostname they would like to test on the textbox. [**I know how to solve this problem]**

When user clicked on the submit button, tests will start running. **[I dont know what the controller should call]**

And user should be able to seeing the result keep updating[refreshing] on the webpage **[some javascript tricks?]**

Comment: Did some research on this and the only alternative I'm getting is the testng plugin for Jenkins. Jenkins is relatively easy to setup so it might be an option worth trying.

Comment: Have you considered some kind of CI, like [tag:Jenkins]?

Answer (score 1):

As Vish said, configure Jenkins to run your test codes and use REST API to run you test cases via POST requests.

> To programmatically schedule a new build, post to this URL: **http://{jenkins_url}/job/{project_name}/build**. If the build has parameters, post to this URL: **http://{jenkins_url}/job/{project_name}/buildWithParameters** and provide the parameters as form data.

You can set up a Jenkins project to accept parameters. For example you can pass a JSON object which includes your tests, classes, configurations (browser, os, site url, etc...) and you can generate your testng.xml programatically from it.

How to create testng.xml programatically: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: Thanks, scheduling a Jenkins build using REST API was the best way to go. I'm awarding you the bounty @peetya, but it would be extremely helpful if you can update your answer to show how I can use the passed parameters from inside my JUnit project.

Comment: JUnit or TestNG? Because you mentioned TestNG before.

Comment: The OP mentioned TestNG, I'm more interested with JUnit.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't check the usernames :) I don't know exactly how can you solve it with JUnit but I think it is almost the same like in TestNG: Create a new Jenkins project with parameters, and add a new String parameter, for example "browserName". And add the following code in your test where the webdriver get inited: **String browserName = System.getenv("browserName");**
After that you can init the webdriver (or that remotewebdriver with the right capabilities) according to the given parameters. I hope it helps, but if you have question do not hesitate to ask again :)